# "I am a college student" vs"I go to college": Which one is generally used?

Tags: word-usage

Recently, One of my friend told me that a sentence "I am a college student" is not generally used to introduce oneself in USA. Instead, a sentence "I go to college" is more general expression.

I have never heard the sentence "I go to college" when someone introduces oneself.
My friends and I always say that "Hi, I'm 000. I'm 22 years old. I'm a college student." when we have to introduce ourselves.

"I am a college student" vs"I go to college": Which one is generally used?

Comment: Just say: *I’m still in college.*

Comment: Speaking for myself, neither: *I'm in school at [X]* or *I'm a student at [X]* or *I'm studying [A] at [X]* was generally sufficient— but then, most people I interacted with knew or assumed I was a student (or they themselves were students), so this step was often unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Context, context, context.

> Hi, I'm Brian, I manage a hedge fund. What do you do?
> I go to college.
>
> Hi, I'm Brian, I'm a hedge fund manager. What about you?
> I'm a college student.

Perhaps your friend goes to a different kind of college.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your friend is wrong -- both of those are fine. It may vary in different parts of the country, but I doubt many people would find one of those phrasings 'wrong'. However, to my ear, both options sound slightly formal -- a colloquial phrasing would be "I'm still in school."